# SQL date order by

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two kind of date format in my table now I want to show the date as order by.

The results look like this:

[image: screenshot of column values]

I want to display the records in ascending format in single format

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: It looks like you've stored these as strings... Can you not store them as dates?

Comment: Eh, do you store `date` as a *string* (`char`/`varchar`)?

Comment: Good luck - you'll need to convert them from strings in their miscellaneous date formats to actual datetime objects first. Is it possible to identify the unique formats you have (you mention two but I can see at least three in your examples)? Please change the underlying column type to avoid this in future.

Comment: as you have added the c# tag I'll give a linq answer - take your list, I'll just call it `l` for now `l = l.OrderBy(d => DateTime.Parse(d.Date)).ToList();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server, it is easiest to convert strings using the built in `convert()` formats.  This is a big inconvenience.  You can try:

```
order by coalesce(try_convert(datetime, meeting_status_date),
                  try_convert(datetime, meeting_status_date, 0),
                  try_convert(datetime, meeting_status_date, 101)
                 )
```

`try_convert()` returns `NULL` if the conversion fails.  The list of conversion formats is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).